# CkEditor 4.3 удаляет классы с тэгов

Tags: html, классы, ckeditor

Такая строка приходит с базы в `editor`

```
<table><tr><td class=desc>512MB, 184-pin DIMM, DDR PC3200 memory module<br /><br /></tr><tr><td><table class="spec"><tr class='even'><td class='specleft'>Memory type </td><td class='specright'>DDR </td><tr class='odd'><td class='specleft'>Frequency speed </td><td class='specright'>400  MHz </td><tr class='even'><td class='specleft'>Module form factor </td><td class='specright'>184-pin DIMM </td><tr class='odd'><td class='specleft'>Memory module capacity </td><td class='specright'>512MB </td><tr class='even'><td class='specleft'>CL </td><td class='specright'>3 </td><tr class='odd'><td class='specleft'>Nominal voltage </td><td class='specright'>2.6  V </td><tr class='even'><td class='specleft'>Chip Organization </td><td class='specright'>64Mx64 </td><tr class='odd'><td class='specleft'>Number of modules </td><td class='specright'>1 </td><tr class='even'><td class='specleft'>Shipping box quantity </td><td class='specright'>15 </td><tr class='odd'><td class='specleft'>Unit Brutto Volume </td><td class='specright'>0,0001702  cubm </td><tr class='even'><td class='specleft'>Unit Net Weight </td><td class='specright'>0,021  kg </td><tr class='odd'><td class='specleft'>Unit Gross Weight </td><td class='specright'>0,036  kg </td></table></table>
```

`editor` переделывает ее в такой вид при этом удаляя классы `class='even'` а так-же почти все и другое

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>desc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <table class="spec">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Memory type</td>
                        <td>DDR</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Frequency speed</td>
                        <td>400 MHz</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Module form factor</td>
                        <td>184-pin DIMM</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Memory module capacity</td>
                        <td>512MB</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>CL</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nominal voltage</td>
                        <td>2.6 V</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Chip Organization</td>
                        <td>64Mx64</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number of modules</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Shipping box quantity</td>
                        <td>15</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Unit Brutto Volume</td>
                        <td>0,0001702 cubm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Unit Net Weight</td>
                        <td>0,021 kg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Unit Gross Weight</td>
                        <td>0,036 kg</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Как это исправить? Это мне не помогает...

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Знаете, сейчас у себя протестировал, версия 4.3.2.

Редактор классы не удаляет, в `config.js` стоит:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

Если убрать этот параметр, то да, классы удаляет. Проверьте, правильно ли вы поставили этот параметр.

Comment: У меня похожая проблема с h3 (обрезается класс), ваше решение не помогло. Возможно есть еще варианты?